# Acer Aspire 4830TG - Windows 10 32 bit

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bluetooth, acer-aspire

The problem is that the laptop keyboard has stopped working. To solve this problem I purchased a [Rapoo](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapoo) wired keyboard. However, it doesn't possess a function key.

Although I have Wi-Fi access I am not able to enable Bluetooth!

Is there a hotkey or other means to enable Bluetooth so that I can transfer photos from my cell to my laptop?

Comment: Use the on-screen keyboard and/or purchase a keyboard with a function key.  You can also take the hardware to somebody so they can potentially fix the keyboard on it.

Comment: Re *"a function key"*: Do you mean a key labelled *"Fn"*?

Comment: Is this Bluetooth toggle part of USB "Consumer control", like volume up and volume down?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the Start Menu
2. Click on the Settings App

[image]

3. Select Devices
4. Select Bluetooth (Left side. The layout/appearance varies depending on what version of Windows 10 you are running. Even the icon is different, so I won't include a screen shot)
5. Enable Bluetooth.

[image]